# complexity - why is this code's complexity O(n²)?

Tags: python, complexity-theory

```
i=0
j=0
while j<n:
   t[j*n+i] =i
   if i = n-1:
      j+=1
      i= 0 
   else:
      i += 1
```

Can you explain to me why this code's complexity is **O**(n<sup>2</sup>)?

Comment: You can google this question and refer various resources.


https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6xkbGLQesk

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you are using while. Then you are traversing over an array. Each of them is n, since they're combined it gives us square, as explained briefly.